# Why am I getting this kind of response for my password in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: root, sudo, package-managers, ubuntu-18.04

When I enter the password for my login it works 
But when I use the same password for installing gcc or g++ or any package it asks me "sorry, try again 
I have not set any other password other than login

Comment: I think you did not set a password to the root so you have to do it. Plz check the answer in the link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/155278/how-do-i-set-the-root-password-so-i-can-use-su-instead-of-sudo

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your problem seems to be related to Ubuntu privileges or package installation. The fact that the affected package is some programming language does not make it a C or C++problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your user is in the `sudo` group by using this command.

```
grep -Po '^sudo.+:\K.*$' /etc/group
```

If your user is not in the root group you'll have to login as root and add your user to the sudo group by typing

```
usermod -a -G sudo yourusername
```

- `-a` will append this new group to the rest of the existing groups
- `-G` is used to specify the list of groups to add

Comment: Using the second it's showing me.   Permission denied cannot lock/etc/passwd